# Não estou conseguindo exibir o nome das pessoas maiores de 18 anos

Tags: c++, string, array, for

```
/*Escreva um programa que receba o nome, profissão e a idade de 10 pessoas, calcule e imprima a quantidade de pessoas maiores de idade (idade >= 18 anos) e seus respectivos nomes.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int idade,cont=0;
    char pro[23];
    char nome[23];
    char nr[23];


    for (int i=0; i<2;i++){
        cout << "Digite o seu " << i+1 <<"º nome, profissão e idade: ";
        scanf("%s", &nome[i]);
        scanf("%s", &pro[i]);
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        if (idade >= 18){
            cont++;
            strcpy(nr[i],nome[i]);
        }
    }

    cout << "número de pessoas maior de 18 anos: " << cont << endl;

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout << "nome: " << nr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, não use tags que não tem haver com o teu código, C#, C++ e C são coisas diferentes. Considere isto uma critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se está usando C++, use a linguagem, não fique misturando com C. Então utilize o `cin` para entrada de dados e `string` para guardar textos. Aí fica mais fácil.

Um dos problemas é que parece que você está querendo guardar até 23 nomes, mas na verdade está guardando um nome com até 23 caracteres, já que um *string* em C é um *array* de `char`. Mudando para o tipo `string` que já é um texto, o *array* fica sendo usado para guardar uma lista de nomes.

Também a cópia está sendo feita sem muito critério (além de usar C). Copiava o que precisava, mas no fundo a lista ficava com todos os elementos, ainda que alguns ficariam com lixo, já que não havia a cópia do nome. Esta lógica precisou ser mudada.

Em um código real eu mudaria várias outras coisas. Criaria uma estrutura para armazenar todos os dados juntos, usaria um `Vector` no lugar do *array*, entre outras pequenas mudanças e reorganizações.

Ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int idade, cont = 0;
    string pro[23];
    string nome[23];
    string nr[23];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "Digite o seu " << i + 1 <<"º nome, profissão e idade: ";
        cin >> nome[i];
        cin >> pro[i];
        cin >> idade;
        if (idade >= 18) nr[cont++] = nome[i];
    }
    cout << "número de pessoas maior de 18 anos: " << cont << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) cout << "nome: " << nr[i] << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/COMPWy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/matfgdvf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/FilterData.cpp).

Comment: Este código irá falhar nos casos em que o nome tem mais que uma palavra. Por exemplo: Ricardo Rodrigues

Comment: É uma outra coisa que eu arrumaria, mas não quis complicar para ele.